# Bash airbase-ng AP alert

Tags: bash

I want to make a bash script that outputs a msg when a device with a specific MAC addr connects to my "MyNetwork" AP.

```
airbase-ng -a 00:00:00:00:00:00 --essid "MyNetwork" -c 6 wlan0mon | grep 'BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB'
```

This command **correctly** outputs airbase-ng lines containing **only** the spesific MAC addr: BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB

When adding this command to a bash script, the "Hello iPhone" msg does not output, even if I am connecting with the correct MAC address

**SOLUTION**

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do

  if airbase-ng -a 00:00:00:00:00:00 --essid "MyNetwork" -c 6 wlan0mon -q | grep 'BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB'; 
  then
     echo "Hello iPhone!"
  fi

  #insert exit condition here
  if false; then
    break
  fi

  #5 second sleep
  sleep 5

done
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I suggest to remove `[[`, `]]`, `$(` and `)`.

Comment: Thank you I added the -q as well and now gets the msg, but the script stops running after the msg is printed, how can I avoid that?

Comment: put the whole thing in an infinite loop like `while true; do <some stuff> done`

Comment: If I where to output to the MAC address from the system response, and not grep for a particular MAC address. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

use a while true to keep it looping all the time

```bash
while true; do 
    #your code
    done
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably do not want to non-stop run this either.  So add a sleep. Putting it all together.

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do

  if [[ $(airbase-ng -a 00:00:00:00:00:00 --essid "MyNetwork" -c 6 wlan0mon | grep 'BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB') ]]; 
  then
    echo "Hello iPhone!"
  fi

  #insert exit condition here
  if false; then
    break
  fi

  #5 second sleep
  sleep 5

done
```

You should probably add some sort of exit condition as well.  Whatever that would be, `break` on that.